# Not able to get the desired output using jq

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I have a json file like below: shopping-items.json

```
{
  "grocery" : [
    {
      "type": "fruits",
      "items" : [
        { "name": "mango", "quantity": "1kg" },
        { "name": "kiwi", "quantity": "2pc" },
        { "name": "apple", "quantity": "2kg" },
        { "name": "banana", "quantity": "6pc" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "vegetables",
      "items" : [
        { "name": "potato", "quantity": "3kg" },
        { "name": "onion", "quantity": "2kg" },
        { "name": "tomato", "quantity": "2kg" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "dryfruits",
      "items" : [
        { "name": "almonds", "quantity": "2kg" },
        { "name": "cachewnut", "quantity": "1kg" },
        { "name": "walnut", "quantity": "1.5kg" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "pulses",
      "items" : [
        { "name": "Blackgram", "quantity": "1kg" },
        { "name": "chickpeas", "quantity": "2kg" },
        { "name": "lentils", "quantity": "1.5kg" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried several jq queries on this set:-

```
$ cat shopping-items.json | jq -r '.grocery[] | .items[] | [.name, .quantity]  | join (",")'
mango,1kg
kiwi,2pc
apple,2kg
banana,6pc
potato,3kg
onion,2kg
tomato,2kg
almonds,2kg
cachewnut,1kg
walnut,1.5kg
Blackgram,1kg
chickpeas,2kg
lentils,1.5kg
```

```
$ cat shopping-items.json | jq -r '.grocery[] | [.type, .items[].name, .items[].quantity] | join (",")'
fruits,mango,kiwi,apple,banana,1kg,2pc,2kg,6pc
vegetables,potato,onion,tomato,3kg,2kg,2kg
dryfruits,almonds,cachewnut,walnut,2kg,1kg,1.5kg
pulses,Blackgram,chickpeas,lentils,1kg,2kg,1.5kg
```

But desired result is as below:-

```
fruits,mango,1kg
fruits,kiwi,2pc
fruits,apple,2kg
fruits,banana,6pc
vegetables,potato,3kg
vegetables,onion,2kg
vegetables,tomato,2kg
dryfruits,almonds,2kg
dryfruits,cachewnut,1kg
dryfruits,walnut,1.5kg
pulses,Blackgram,1kg
pulses,chickpeas,2kg
pulses,lentils,1.5kg
```

There is a way, but I feel it's not efficient. Looking for an efficient way for this result.

```sh
filename=shopping-items.json
count=`cat ${filename} | jq -c '.grocery[] | keys' | wc -l`
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $count ]
do
  var_type=`cat ${filename} | jq -r .grocery[$counter].type`
  jq --arg var_type $var_type --argjson c $counter --raw-output '.grocery[$c].items[] | [$var_type, .name, .quantity] | join(",")' ${filename}
  counter=`expr $counter + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result, you can simply invoke jq once using thie following jq program:

```
.grocery[]
| [.type] + ( .items[] | [.name, .quantity])
| join (",")
```

See it in action at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/R1BBWHkKvO)

[image: jqplay.org]

Comment: This worked for me to get the desired output. I was not much familiar with variable concept. Looked for it and applied here
<br/>
cat shopping-items.json | jq -r '.grocery[] | .type as $parent | .items[] | [$parent, .name, .quantity] | join(",")'

Comment: This answer would be worth an upvote if it contained a complete working example and not just a reference to a concept one would need to look up now.

Comment: @Alfe - See the jqplay.org link.

Comment: @peak I've seen that.  SO rules ask to not just link to a place with an answer but instead have the contents complete in their answer.  To avoid answers getting useless just because another site goes down in the future.

Comment: @Alfe - As mentioned, the jq program is complete.  The question already gives a complete sample input and sample output, and shows the OP knows how to invoke jq. So  just repeating the input, output, and manner of invocation would be superfluous here.

Comment: Right, I was, in fact, referring to the statement "You could use a variable to store .type" and the answer of OP "I was not much familiar with variable concept. Looked for it and applied here …".  It would be nice to have an example for exactly this approach because it happens that people stumble across this answer in search for examples of using variables in jq and then they are left alone without an example again.  Nevermind.

Comment: @Alfe - The quotation you mentioned is from a comment that was made after this answer was posted.  Since using a jq variable for `.type` has no advantage here, I've modified the answer to avoid confusion.